# Maven max. test number per thread, when running in parallel

Tags: maven, serenity-bdd

I have a total of 405 tests. They are all executed fine when running on a single thread. However, when trying to run it in parallel, it seems the number of tests is not being properly allocated per thread.

So, for example, executing it using 3 threads:

```
mvn  integration-test -Dwebdriver.remote.url=http://selenium-hub.project.svc.cluster.local:4444/wd/hub \
                      -Dwebdriver.remote.driver=chrome                 \
                      -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome                         \
                      -Dconfig.threads=3                                 \
                      -Dserenity.batch.size=3 \
                      -Dserenity.batch.number=<"from 1 to 3"> \
                      -Dserenity.batch.strategy=DIVIDE_BY_TEST_COUNT        \ 
                      -Dserenity.take.screenshots=FOR_EACH_ACTION
```

After triggered maven, as according to the sample above, the tests have been allocated as follows:

```
Thread 1: 106
Thread 2:  96
Thread 3: 103
   Total: 305
```

The funny thing is that those numbers vary, changing the tests count per thread on every execution.

As well, it is like it is counting 4 threads instead of 3.

I'm running those tests using Jenkins, hosted in an Openshift environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround by increasing the number of threads (e.g. from 3 to 4). It looks like somehow there is a limitation regarding the number of tests executed per thread.

I will search for this config. and keep this post updated in case I find something.